# Execute a line in vimrc at the end

Tags: vim

I want to set `textwidth` to 50 when a file in the form `jrnl*.txt` is detected. So, I tried to put the following line into an empty `~/.vim/vimrc` file:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile jrnl*.txt set fo+=t tw=50
```

And it works correctly.

However, I'm using now [Vim-Boostrap](https://github.com/avelino/vim-bootstrap), which is a `vimrc` generator with a lot of plugins.

I have tried to write my code at the end of the new `vimrc` but when I a run vim, `textwidth` is equal to `0`. If I launch `:scriptnames` I see a lot of scripts that are executed after my code, therefore I suppose `textwidth` is overwritten.

I wonder if there is a method to execute my line at the end and thus avoid the overwritten issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your hypothesis that plugins are overriding your settings is probably right. Putting your code at the end of `vimrc` would also not help as `vimrc` is loaded before plugins.

One way to get around this is to use after directory.
Create a file `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/text.vim`

Add your code to this file.
Vim will load this script after it loads plugins.